Flutter web Firebase cloud messaging function doesnt respond
I'm trying to call the function requestPermission() from FirebaseMessaging. For some reason, this doesnt return anything and the function execution is stopping.
I'm programming on VSCode on a windows 11 machine, running on web (Edge). I also tried on android phone without success.
Here the code:
void initPushNotification() async {
    print("in async");
    String? fcmToken;
    try {
      final fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
      print("requestperm");
      final response = await fcm.requestPermission();
      print(response.authorizationStatus.name);
      print("got perm");

      if (kIsWeb) {
        print("is web");

        fcmToken = await fcm.getToken(
            vapidKey:
                "A VAPID KEY HERE");
        print("got token");
      } else {
        fcmToken = await fcm.getToken();
      }
      print(
          fcmToken);
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
    print("end async");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("initstate");
    try {
      initPushNotification();
    } catch (err) {
      print("catch");

      print(err);
    }
    print("finish initstate");
  }

Console ouput:
initstate
in async
finish initstate
requestperm

Some infos in the pubspec:
environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.3


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  firebase_core: ^3.6.0
  firebase_auth: ^5.3.1
  firebase_storage: ^12.3.4
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^5.4.4
  firebase_messaging: ^15.1.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

I have no error of any kind on the console, even on the web console.
I expected the function requestPermission() to actually request permissions ...
I searched the web to find some solutions and followed the firebase docs: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive?hl=fr.
Also tried this even if it looks a bit suspicious to me:
Adding stuff to my index.html under web folder:
// IG the version here arent correct but i would expect a different kind of error if it was this
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>
    const firebaseConfig = {
       apiKey: '...',
      appId: '...',
      messagingSenderId: '...',
      projectId: '...',
      authDomain: '...',
      storageBucket: '...',
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
      });
    }
  </script>

The firebase-messaging-sw.js:
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

   /*Update with yours config*/
  const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: '...',
      appId: '...',
      messagingSenderId: '...',
      projectId: '...',
      authDomain: '...',
      storageBucket: '...',
 };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  /*messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);*/
  messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('Received background message ', payload);

    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: payload.notification.body,
    };

    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
  });

What am i missing ?

Follow This Step by Step Process
Step 1 : Try to launch on chrome not on Edge browser
: -> If work then no need to change
Step 2 : If get same result on any browser
Like if app not launch or launch but not anything view in browser (Like white screen) and not received any error.
Do Following change in index.html file in web directory of your project
Check following function must be last  tab in index file
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function (appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

for more reference I provide you whole index.html file of my personal flutter project (TechCureIndia)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <!-- Description -->
  <meta name="description"
    content="We are experts in workstatuions and gaming pc's | AI & deep learning pc | Architechture & Engineering pc | visual designer & video editor pc | trading pc | Audio production pc | Gaming pc | amd series | custom liquid cooling setup | Cryptocurrency mining rigs | All IT peripherals & much more.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <!-- Change TITLE  -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Tech Cure India">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" /> -->

  <!-- Use .ico favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

  <!-- Change TITLE -->
  <title>Tech Cure India</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = "2091515534";
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>


  <!-- This is for js in flutterWeb-->
  <script src="appscript.js" defer></script>
  <!-- This is for load our css file-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Toastify CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js/src/toastify.min.css">

  <!-- PDF View -->
  <script>
    var dartPdfJsVersion = "3.2.146";
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Loading Indicator  Below-->
  <div class="loading">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Loading Indicator  Above-->


  <!-- <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script> -->
  <!-- Move above line bottom most-->


  <!-- Firebase SetUp script type = 'module'-->
  <!-- <script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBenD4UHfJiCcodpSzYKFe4buxRg_ZfZic",
      authDomain: "techcureindia.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "techcureindia",
      storageBucket: "techcureindia.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1016267859555",
      appId: "1:1016267859555:web:45e1e213f671b886323a56",
      measurementId: "G-VNSZL96YJM"
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  </script> -->

  <!-- Firebase INIT way 2.0 -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourKey"></script>
  <script>


    // Your web app's Firebase configuration

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBenD4UHfJiCcodpSzYKFe4buxRg_ZfZic",
      authDomain: "techcureindia.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "techcureindia",
      storageBucket: "techcureindia.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1016267859555",
      appId: "1:1016267859555:web:45e1e213f671b886323a56",
      measurementId: "G-VNSZL96YJM"
    };

    /// Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
  <!-- Firebase INIT way 2.0 -->


  <!-- syncfusion-PDF -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.11.338/pdf.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.11.338/pdf.worker.min.js";
  </script>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function (appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>

If you still get error please provide whole index.html file of your project
Hope this will help you
REASON BEHIND THIS IF NOT WORK IN EDGE BUT WORK IN CHROME
Flutter web uses different renderers (CanvasKit for desktop and HTML for mobile). So, sometime Browser Developing Tools and Performance are required for debugging flutter web. In Edge or other browser like opera & Firefox not have such advance web developing tools are available in chrome. its depend of rendering process of browser.

So, i changed nothing about the code.
It worked on Chrome but still not on Edge for some reasons that i would be very curious about.
Also it work now on android. I did flutter clean then flutter pub get then firebase configure .

Let me, update my answer with this reason. and if you like  please upvote my answer
